# Writing linq/lambda query between two tables to get values using EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Hi I have two entity models that has data in tables as:

```
Table Group
id    name
1     NW
2     SW
3     NE

Second Table is 
Location
id  groupId  count
1      1      34
2      2       5
3      2       90
4      1       33
5      1       23
```

I want to write a linq query or using context in EF so that i can group by each groupId so that result is

```
groupdId  1
    {count 34, 33, 23}
groupId 2
    {count 90,5}
```

I have tried following

```
from e in DbContext.Set<Group>()
join a in DbContext.Set<locatin>() on e.Id equals a.groupId
Select new Test
{
    groupId= e.groupdId
    tables = new List<tbl>()
    {
        count= a.count;
    }
}

public class Test  
{
    public int groupId {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<gbl> Tables {get; set;}
}

public class tbl
{
    public int count {get; set;}
}
```

In writing the query when I get to `count=a.count`, I get intellisense error can not resolve. Please let me know how to correct my query so that I get heading of groupId then another array with count numbers only. Thanks.

Comment: This is giving an error because count is not a List<tbl> property it is a tbl property, what you need to do is:

tables = new List<tbl>
{
new tbl{ count= a.count; }
}

Comment: In current example Location table has all the data to provide the solution, but In my view you need a grouping of tables Group and Location for the usage in the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will work in this case:

```
var result =
    groups.Join(locations,g=>g.id,l=>l.groupId,(g,l)=>new {l})
          .GroupBy(x =>x.l.groupId,x=>x.l.count)
          .Select(y=>new Test
                    {
                    groupId= y.Key,
                    tables = y.Select(n => new tbl{count = n})
                    });
```

Following are the steps:

1. Join two tables `groups` and `locations` using the `id` and `groupid`
2. `GroupBy` the result and project the `count`
3. `Select` and result should be `IEnumerable<Test>`

Following is my complete code, that I have used to create the solution (using LinqPad):

```
 void Main()
{
    var groups = Group.CreateList();

    var locations = Location.CreateList();

    var result =
    groups.Join(locations,g=>g.id,l=>l.groupId,(g,l)=>new {l})
          .GroupBy(x =>x.l.groupId,x=>x.l.count)
          .Select(y=>new Test
                    {
                    groupId= y.Key,
                    tables = y.Select(n => new tbl{count = n})
                    });

        result.Dump();
    } 

public class Group
{
    public int id;
    public string name;

    public static List<Group> CreateList()
    {
    return new List<Group>
        {
            new Group
            {
            id = 1,
            name = "NW"
            },
            new Group
            {
            id = 2,
            name = "SW"
            },
            new Group
            {
            id = 3,
            name = "NE"
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Location
{
    public int id;
    public int groupId;
    public int count;

    public static List<Location> CreateList()
    {
    return new List<Location>
        {
            new Location
            {
            id = 1,
            groupId = 1,
            count = 34
            },
            new Location
            {
            id = 2,
            groupId = 2,
            count = 5
            },
            new Location
            {
            id = 3,
            groupId = 2,
            count = 90
            },
            new Location
            {
            id = 4,
            groupId = 1,
            count = 33
            },
            new Location
            {
            id = 5,
            groupId = 1,
            count = 23
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Test  
{
   public int groupId {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<tbl> tables {get; set;}
}
public class tbl
{
  public int count {get; set;}
}
```